# Plotting a "posterior median surface"

Tags: prediction, spatial, posterior, hierarchical-bayesian, pymc

As part of reproducing a model I described partially in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654487/multivariate-normal-changes-value-of-variable-in-pymc) on Stack Overflow, I want to obtain a plot of a posterior distribution. The (spatial) model describes the selling price of some properties as a Bernoulli distribution depending on whether the property is expensive (1) or cheap (0). In equations:

$$y_{i} \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p_{i})$$
$$p_{i} \sim \text{logit}^{-1}(b_{0} + b_{1}\text{LivingArea}/1000 + b_{2}\text{Age} + w({\bf{s}}))$$
$$w({\bf{s}}) \sim \text{MVN}({\bf{0}}, {\bf{\Sigma}}) $$

where $y_{i}$ is the binary result 1 or 0, $p_{i}$ is the probability of being cheap or expensive, $w({\bf{s}})$ is a spatial random variable where $\bf{s}$  represents its position. All of this for each  $i = \{1, ..., 70\}$ because there are 70 properties in the dataset. $\bf{\Sigma}$ is a covariance matrix based on the geographical position of the data points. If you're curious about this model, the dataset can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=41us4HVj).

The plot I want to obtain is the following contour plot:

[image]

The figure is described as "Image plot of the posterior median surface of the latent process $w({\bf{s}})$, binary spatial model". The book also says this:

> Figure 5.8 shows the image plot with overlaid contour lines for the
>   posterior mean surface of the latent $w({\bf{s}})$ process.

However, there are only 70 pairs of points in the dataset. I suppose that, in order to produce a contour plot, I need to estimate $w({\bf{s}})$ in 70*70 points. So, my question is: How do I produce this posterior median surface? So far I have samples of posterior distributions for all the parameters involved (using PyMC) and I know that I can predict $y^*$ at a new point using the posterior predictive distribution. However, I don't know how to predict values $w({\bf{s}})$ at a new point $s^*$. Maybe I'm wrong and the plot wasn't constructed by prediction but by interpolation.

**UPDATE**:

First, this is the median of the posterior distribution of $w({\bf{s}})$ at each location where there is a property. This is based on the MCMC trace for $w$.

[image]

And this is the interpolation (with a contour plot) using a radial basis function:

[image]

(If you're interested in the code, let me know)

As you can see, there are significant differences in the plots. A couple of questions:

1. How can I know if these differences are explained by the interpolation procedure?
2. Maybe, there are important variations in the posterior distribution of $w({\bf{s}})$ that I calculated and the one showed in the book. How much variation is acceptable between MCMC simulations? Even my own parameters change a bit depending on the sampling I use (Metropolis, Metropolis Adaptive.)
3. Is there some Bayesian procedure to predict points $w(s)$ in order to generate a contour plot as I did using radial basis function?

Comment: Interpolation *is* prediction!  (Because $w$ is a process, coming up with a value of $w$ at any unobserved location amounts to guessing the value of a random variable. Prediction, by definition, is guessing the value of a random variable.)

Comment: Sure. I meant to say interpolation as opposed to Bayesian prediction. By the way, I tried to use interpolation with nearest neighbor and I got awful results.

Comment: You probably should get terrible results if you use the raw data in an interpolation program, because it was solving a different problem. You want a contour plot *only* of the $w$ term but the program was (I presume) using the $y_i$.

Comment: No, I was using the median of the posterior distribution for each $w(s)$.

Comment: At which spatial locations $s$ did you compute the median of the posterior distribution? I believe the principal motivation behind running a model of this sort is to track the distribution of $w(s)$ at *all* points where you are interested in predicting its values, which--in the case of this contour map--would be all 4900 grid nodes.

Comment: I created a grid based on every possible combination of longitude and latitude, so there are 4900 points being predicted.

Comment: Then I do not understand why you need an interpolation algorithm: all that remains is to display the grid of median values as an image.

Comment: Oh, no. I only have 70 points from the median of the posterior distribution of $w(s_{i})$ with $i = {1,...,70}$. I interpolated 4900 points using those 70 points, but the results don't seem to match the plot I showed above.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "70 pair of points." You have stated you created a grid with "4900 points being predicted."  With a Bayesian prediction algorithm you should therefore obtain a posterior distribution for every one of those 4900 points.  It remains unclear (to me, at least) what you're really doing and what the problem actually is.

Comment: I corrected that a minute ago. It is not "70 pair of points" but "70 points". I can't (as far I know) predict the 4900 points because I only have a trace of the posterior distribution. I have no closed form and no likelihood. By "Bayesian prediction algorithm" you mean the posterior predictive distribution, right?

Comment: In your question you write, "I know that I can predict $y^{*}$ at a new point using the posterior predictive distribution."  Can't you then predict $w$ just as easily, and do so at 4900 points?

Comment: I wish I could. Well, I don't know if that is possible. What would be the likelihood in that case? And how to deal with that in MCMC context. It is not clear to me how I can predict $w(s)$ at a new point $s^*$.

Comment: Enough useful additional information has emerged in these comments that at this point you should consider editing the question to include this information and perhaps even reformulate what you are asking for.  There are active members on this site who are real experts in Bayesian predictions, even if they might not be experts in spatial analysis *per se*, so I believe a rephrasing that focuses on the former might get their attention and indicate how they can help you.

Comment: Sure. I was running another MCMC to get a plot of the medians of the posterior distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that the author used a Gaussian process to produce the interpolation. I think that is true because an exercise in the book describes a very similar problem to this one and requires a plot based on a Gaussian process.

I tried it and I think the resulting plot shares features with the posterior median surface of the original question. This is the median of the posterior distribution of $w(s)$ as above (it is slightly different because I ran another MCMC simulation):

[image]

And this is the interpolation based on a Gaussian process:

[image]

As you can see, the method of interpolation makes a huge difference.